# "Infinite-living" Cookies possible?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been using cookies on my experimental game for a while, and I wonder if you could set a cookie's lifetime to **infinite**.

Currently, my code sets the cookie's expiry date to 999 999 999 days after set, and it resets the expiry date upon the game's load.

But is there a legitimate way to have a JavaScript cookie last forever?

Comment: No, all yuo can do is making it really long.

Comment: The average human lifespan is around 30,000 days. In practical terms how does your solution differ from 'forever'?

Comment: What's your use case (what exactly are using it for in your game) ? There is probably a more elegant solution

Comment: @Michael I'm currently using it as save points in my game, so the user can resume playing at a certain point.

Comment: What's about local storage or a rudimentary account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage`.

It does not expire unless you run a script to clear it or user decides to do it himself.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! How does a user clear a localStorage cookie anyway? I know you can delete it via code, but can a user do an equivalent?

Comment: @DominatorX Many browsers will clear localStorage along with cookies. For instance, Google Chrome's "[Clear browsing data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582)" will clear both in tandem, as "cookies and other site and plug-in data".

Comment: There are a lot of various ways - browse in a private session, call `localStorage.clear()` through console or simply go to debugger--> Resources-->Local Storage.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

Setting cookies to have expiration dates in the distant future is risky, as [dates beyond January 19th, 2038 may be interpreted incorrectly by some systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Years after 9999 are also likely to cause issues, as date parsing libraries will often assume that years are always four digits long.

It's probably best if you don't set cookie expiration dates more than 10 years into the future. Most users will likely replace their computers before such a cookie expires, assuming that your web site even exists then.

Comment: Not being negative about your site in particular; 10 years is just a very long time on the Internet. Most web sites don't last that long in general.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a few reasons.  First, there's not a built-in feature for an infinite cookies.  Secondly, the user can always clear their cookies, no matter what date you specify, so there's still no guarantee.

Edit: to comment on `localStorage`, that is an option, but you still have no guarantees that it will be allowed (I don't allow that on my browser, though I am a paranoid lunatic who also blocks all non-whitelisted scripts, so I'm not the typical user), and the user can still clear that.